# What do the red and blue buffs do?

Tags: paragon

There are red and blue buffs in the jungle of Paragon, which you get by killing specific camps and picking up the appropriately colored orb, which then orbits around you for a while.

But...what exactly do they do? I'm sure they're beneficial, so I've been grabbing them when possible, but knowing exactly how I benefit from each one might help my decision making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the paragon [wiki](http://paragon.wiki/Jungle#Buffs):

- The red buff gives "Increased Damage by twenty-five percent and a small movement speed bonus on hit."
- The blue buff gives "Increased Mana Regeneration and Cooldown Reduction by Twenty Percent."

Note: All buffs last for two and a half minutes when acquired. If you are killed by an opposing player while carrying a buff, that buff will then be transferred to them and the countdown timer for that buff will restart.

Also possibly of interest, the black buff gives "Increased Structure Damage and Attack Speed."

Comment: Ooh, I didn't even know there was a black buff. I will need to explore the jungle more.